# How can we prove that $z^{n+1} \to 0_{\mathbb{C}}$ as $n\to \infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

In the book of *Function of One Complex Variable* by Conway, at page 31, it is given that

[image]

However, normally, if $z$ was a real number, we could argue that $z^{n+1}$ goes to zero as $n \to \infty$ if $|z| < 1$, but in the case of complex numbers, if $|z = a + bi| = a^2 + b^2 < 1$, then, for example,
$$z^2 = a^2 - b^2 + (2ab)i,$$
and we can see that it might be the case that $2ab \geq b$, so if we see z = (a,b), then $z^2 = (a^2 - b^2, 2ab)$, and the statement $z^n \to 0_{\mathbb{C}}$ means both of the components of $z^n$ goes to $0_{\mathbb{R}}.

However, even when we square the number $z$, the components does not need to decrease, so how can we be sure that if $|z| < 1$, then $z^n \to 0_{\mathbb{C}}$ as $n\to \infty$ ?

**tl:dr;**

How can we prove that $z^{n+1} \to 0_{\mathbb{C}}$ as $n\to \infty$ ?

Comment: Hint: $$|z^n|=|z|^n$$

Comment: Correction:for $z^n\to0$ you need $|z|<1$ (so $|z|\leq1$ is not enough).

Comment: @drhab Yes, that is correct; it is just a typo.

Comment: @Did Thanks for the hint. I knew that, but when you write it, I thought I could use $\epsilon - \delta$ definition, which directly leads to the result that I'm looking for.

Comment: A small note, but I think you need the stronger condition $\lvert z \rvert \lt 1,$ since, for example, if $z=i$, then $\lvert z \rvert =1$ and $z^n$ diverges.

Comment: What is the reason for the down vote ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$z^{n+1} \to 0 \iff \lim |z^{n+1} - 0| = 0 \iff |z|^{n+1} \to 0.$

First iff: let $z^n = x_n +\mathrm i y_n$, then by 
$$
\max(|x_n|, |y_n|) \leqslant |z^n| \leqslant |x_n| + |y_n|,
$$
we conclude the first iff.

Example: $z^2 = (a^2 - b^2) + \mathrm i 2ab$, then $a^2 -b^2 \leqslant a^2 + b^2$, $2ab \leqslant 2|ab| \leqslant a^2+b^2$.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking how to prove the first "iff" part.

Answer (score 1):

Just write your complex numbers in polar form — are you familiar with the polar representation of complex numbers?

Write $z=re^{i\theta}=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$ with $r=|z|$. Then $z^{n}=r^{n}e^{in\theta}$; $|e^{in\theta}| = 1$ for all real $n,\theta$ thus

$$|z^{n}|=|r^{n}|\to0$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer; that is also a clear picture of what is happening, but I haven't examined the polar representation thoroughly, so I did not consent myself to use it.